# About the Adjoint of a Matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I am a neophyte undergraduate student reviewing multivariate analysis. I am learning from  *Mathematical Tools for Applied Multivariate Analysis* (J.D. Caroll, P.E. Green).

I covered the **co-factor expansion method** to yield the determinant of a matrix. In my textbook, it is said that for a 3x3 matrix, d(A) is based on the entries of the first row:

- d(A) = a11(a22 * a33 - a32 * a23) - a12(a21 * a33 - a31 * a23) +
  a13(a21 * a32-a31 * a22)

Which, for the following matrix, yields a value of -441:

2 4 -3

5 7 6

-8 1 9

- d(A) = 2(57) - 4(93) + -3(61) = -441

So far, so good. However, when I moved on to **finding the adjoint of the same matrix**, I found [another method on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yi5qzNee7dc) where the co-factor entries are applied to the entire matrix, row by row. Meaning that beyond a11, a12, a13 (i.e., first row), the minors and co-factor values are also computed for a21, a22, a23, ..., a33. Which, for the same matrix A above, would yield a co-factor matrix:

cf(A):

57 93 61

39 -6 34

45 27 -6

**My first question then is: Why is determinant of A NOT obtained through the computation of all co-factors derived from all row entries of A? Why does the formula for d(A) stops at the first row?**

Then, my second question pertains to the transpose of cf(A). In the same video, a signed matrix is used to determine the signs of the transpose of cf(A) (i.e., the adjoint of A).

pos neg pos

neg pos neg

pos neg pos

**I am not sure what the transpose rules are in relation to this signed matrix. In my own case study, the co-factor matrix transpose would be, without sign alteration T(cfA):**

57 39 45

93 -6 27

61 34 -6

**How will the transposed entries change in light of the signed matrix?**

Thank you in advance for any kind mind who'll be willing to enlighten me.

Daniel